# Change comments form title on a page by page basis

Tags: php, functions, comments, filters, customization

I'm looking to change the comments form title (my theme defaults this to "Leave a Comment" or "Leave a reply to").

I thought perhaps I could add a hook to comment_form_defaults but my snippet below isn't working... any thoughts?

```
    <?php 
add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'askQuestion');

function askQuestion($defaults) {
  $defaults['title_reply'] = 'Ask a Question';
  $defaults['title_reply_to'] = 'Your text %s';
  return $defaults;
}
?>
```

This is being added to the HTML editor of the page editor within wordpress. We  are using the ExecPHP plugin to compile  code within posts/pages. We are looking for a way to do this on just this page, not every comment form on our blog.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: s2clean - http://www.primothemes.com/post/product/s2clean-theme-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

Add the code to your comment template file or your functions.php with a page conditional. The comments file depends on your theme, by default it is `comments.php` , but it could be named anything, you need to look at your theme's code.

For example if it's the contact page,

```
  if (is_page('Contact'))
    // do something
```

Comment: I thought about this, but how can I keep from having to re-add this to comments.php everytime I upgrade wordpress or my theme?

Comment: WordPress does not touch theme files when it upgrades, your theme on the other hand depends but typically they do not over-write anything you added, you can safeguard this rather easily but writing a custom functions file like my_comment_function.php and simply include it in functions.php.